# How to change enum type column in laravel migration?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, enums, migration

I am using [Laravel 5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1) and I have a table called packages with this structure:

```
id              int(11)
weight          decimal(10,2)           
weight_unit     enum('Kg.', 'Gm.')
```

I would like to change the `weight_unit` enum to:

`weight_unit     enum('Grams','Kgs.','Pounds')`

For this I create the following migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('packages', function ($table) {
        $table->enum('weight_unit', array('Grams','Kgs.','Pounds'))->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

But when I run the migration I receive an error:

```
Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform  

may not support it.
```

How can I change this enum?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use the `DB::statement` method:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE packages MODIFY COLUMN weight_unit ENUM('Grams', 'Kgs', 'Pounds')");
```

Comment: You can only use databases that support the ENUM type with this solution, just be aware. For example, running tests with SQLite will break. If portability is not a concern and you always use MySQL, this works fine.

Comment: FYI, you've got a syntax error. If you don't want to repeat the column name you have to use `MODIFY` instead of `CHANGE`.

Comment: Laravel migration has an abstraction layer, which makes this answer right for MySQL but not for PostgresSQL. For the last one it [emulates the enum to a varchar with constraint](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/PostgresGrammar.php#L520..L527) (don't know why since postgres [supports enum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-enum.html)). That is if you want the same result than a column originaly created as enum by a laravel migration.

Comment: I've fixed the syntax as per @mpen's comment

Comment: Statement isn't supported in SQLite so PHPUnit tests will fail!

Answer (score 28):

This worked for me when adding a new enum value to the modified enum column.

Add the following to the `up()` method:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE packages MODIFY weight_unit ENUM('Grams', 'Kgs', 'Pounds', 'new value') NOT NULL");
```

Then in the `down()` method you can revert the change that was made:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE packages MODIFY weight_unit ENUM('Grams', 'Kgs', 'Pounds') NOT NULL");
```

***Note: before the enum value is removed it needs to be changed to another enum value that will be retained.***

Answer (score 14):

```
$table->enum('level', ['easy', 'hard']);
```

Comment: Ram, full example migration:

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateCampaignConversionTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('campaign_conversion', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->enum('status', array(
                'pending',
                'completed',
                'failed',
                'expired'
            ))->nullable()->index('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: this creates an enum for the column. this cannot be used to modify the values of an existing enum for a column

Answer (score 14):

I think that is fixed on Laravel 10 by adding support for native column modifying.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/45487

So from Laravel 10 you can do this:

```
Schema::table('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->enum('type', ['contract', 'permanent', 'partial'])->change();
});
```

I tried the same migration on fresh Laravel 9.55.0 and 10.0.2 application:

[laravel-9.52.0.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Q1J.jpg)

[laravel-10.0.2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2kJb.jpg)

update :
if you have installed "doctrine/dbal" in your project call
`Schema::useNativeSchemaOperationsIfPossible()` method within the boot method of your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class or within your migrations files to be able to use native schema operations like it is mentioned in the GitHub pull request above.

Comment: FWIW, it **doesn't** seem to work with Laravel 10.1.5 running 10.8.3-MariaDB Homebrew on a Mac...

Comment: @WilliamTurrell, I just tried with 10.11.2-MariaDB and it's working. 

https://imgur.com/a/08NCPrM

Answer (score 5):

**In case you dont want to lose your data** and update it with the new values I came up with this solution:

```
// Include old and new enum values
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE packages MODIFY COLUMN weight_unit ENUM('Kg.', 'Gm.', 'Grams', 'Kgs', 'Pounds')");
// Replace Kg. with Kgs
Packages::where('weight_unit', 'Kg.')->update(['weight_unit' => 'Kgs']);
// Replace Gm. with Grams
Packages::where('weight_unit', 'Gm.')->update(['weight_unit' => 'Grams']);
// Delete old values
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE packages MODIFY COLUMN weight_unit ENUM('Grams', 'Kgs', 'Pounds')");
```

This way you can replace your old values with the new ones.

Comment: Using model classes in the migration files is a bad practice because of the risk of attributes unsync, etc. One should do `DB::table('packages')->where(...)->update(...);` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can add custom constructor to migration and explain to Doctrine that `enum` should be treated like string.

```
public function __construct(\Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Version $version)
{
    parent::__construct($version);

    $this->platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
}
```

Comment: I can't understand which class you want this to be in. You say inside the migration so I assume you mean the class that extends `Migration`. But I get the error `__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Version, none given, called in /home/vagrant/asb/vendor/larave
  l/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php on line 335` and also, I can't see any `\Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Version` namespace but I do see `Doctrine\DBAL\Version` and `Doctrine\Common\Version`

Comment: Jonathan, you're most likely missing the doctrine/dbal package.

Comment: Also if this code belongs in the migration constructor then this will work better on newer Laravel versions: `DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');` The constructor also takes 0 arguments.

Answer (score 4):

add this before change() call :

```
DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
```

Comment: how this is not a "default instruction" on Laravel migration? Im stuck try to find my error for hours... Thanks sir!

Answer (score 2):

with default value. add this in `up()`:

```
\DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `patient_appointments` CHANGE `status` `status` ENUM('pending','wait','approved', 'consulted') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending';");
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve this by removing and adding constraints. This has made sure that my existing data is also is intact.

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE purchases DROP CONSTRAINT purchases_ref_check");
$types = ['single', 'monthly', 'biannual', 'amount', 'other'];
$result = join( ', ', array_map(function( $value ){ return sprintf("'%s'::character varying", $value); }, $types) );
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE purchases add CONSTRAINT purchases_ref_check CHECK (ref::text = ANY (ARRAY[$result]::text[]))");
```

Comment: This is the only valid solution for a case of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score -1):

In postgres, I don't find out more elegant solution but this, example:

```
public function up()
{
    if (Schema::hasColumn('plan_fibras', 'type')) {
        Schema::table('plan_fibras', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropColumn('type');
        });
    }

    if (!Schema::hasColumn('plan_fibras', 'type')) {
        Schema::table('plan_fibras', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->enum('type', ['PF', 'PJ', 'FIBRA X'])->nullable();
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    if (Schema::hasColumn('plan_fibras', 'type')) {
        Schema::table('plan_fibras', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropColumn('type');
        });
    }
}
```