# Change enum column of Table in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table which i created by migration, and I set the a column in the currency table to `enum` and it can only contain 3 values. How can i change the column `symbol` to varchar at the moment `symbol` is of enum property and also remove the `$symbols` variable from the column

This is my migration

```
public function up()
{
    $symbols = ['₦', '$', '£'];
    Schema::create('currencies', function (Blueprint $table) use($symbols) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->string('code', 5);
        $table->enum('symbol', $symbols);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{   
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
    Schema::dropIfExists('currencies');
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
}
```

Comment: Is this in production or still in development?  You may have to write a raw statement to alter the column for production systems since Laravel in the past has had issues with updating enum columns.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496518/how-to-change-enum-type-column-in-laravel-migration?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: This is in production, can you please add your answer of how i should use raw statement @devon

Comment: Use DB::statement but use the SQL that your database engine (guessing MySQL) supports to update that column.  Test on a  dev server before running on production.

Comment: Please @devon based on the name of my table and the column how should the Db::statement syntax be, please can you add the answer, I believe that will solve my problem

Comment: @IrueneAdokiye you'll need to do some research yourself.  The only thing different for Laravel is you'd put the SQL inside DB::statement().

Answer (score 2):

Create a new migration with the following steps/components:

- First rename your current symbol column to something else.
- Then create the symbol column the way that you want it, for example like you said, as a varchar.

  ```
  Schema::table('currencies', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->renameColumn('symbol','tempName'); //Rename to temp column
      $table->string('symbol'); //New symbol column
  });
  ```
- Then loop through all existing rows and take the value of the temporary column that you renamed symbol to and set them on the newly created symbol column. (Can be done several ways, you should be able to figure that out)
- Then remove the temporary column.

  ```
  Schema::table('currencies', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->dropColumn('tempName'); //Remove the temp column
  });
  ```

Comment: Please how can the looping be done, that will help, Thanks @teun

Comment: If you have a currencies model you can do something like this:
$currencies = Currencies::all();
foreach($currencies as $currency){
  $currency->symbol = $currency->tempName;
  $currency->save();
}

Or write a query that updates them all at once