# Change Column datatype with existing enum col in laravel

Tags: database, laravel

I have a users table for my project, i already have column Role ( enum ['admin', 'student', 'teacher']) in my table, and i want to change the designation column ('string'), but as per laravel docs we cannot update the column with enum datatype, so in this case what should i do, i am new to laravel.

Comment: You could add the new column, then write a migration to transfer the data, and then remove the old column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change enum column of Table in LARAVEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50743289/change-enum-column-of-table-in-laravel)

Comment: changes direct database filed type, without loosing any data.

Comment: @mike he dont want to change the enum column , he already has enum column and he want to change the another column.

Comment: Ahh sorry it seemed like the goal was to change the enum column to a string. if this is not the case than i am not sure what the intentions of the user are. Can you maybe add some context and a code example or an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column with data type string then write a simple query to update to copy the enum value into the string column

```
update tableName set columnA = ColumnB;
```

then drop the old column with enum type.

If you want to use migration then first create a migration to add the string column then run a query to copy the data into string column. Now write another migration to drop the column with enum type.